# Why I can't see any Images within HTML codes?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a Asp.net core project. I am trying to set background image for a specific page view, but it doesn't show any image! I was wondering if I need to modify any codes in the main style.css file.

Here's the view page

```css
#mycontact:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("~/image/RealHome.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(50px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.left {
  background: url("~/image/RealHome.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div id="mycontact" class="container">
    <div class="contact-box">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <form action="mailto:info@amrealestatesellfast.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
          <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Email">
          <textarea placeholder="Message" class="field"></textarea>
          <button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Please show the RENDERED page

Comment: does the rest of your CSS work as expected? what is your directory structure like?

Comment: `~/image/RealHome.jpg` does not look like a valid image path. How does it look in the browser? You likely want `./image/ReaHome.jpg`

Comment: Ah yes `~/` only works in razor pages, not in css files

Answer (score -1):

the `~` notation is invalid to the browser, try to remove or use the absolute address like `http://domain/path/to/the/image.jpg`

Comment: You saved my life! It used to work before though! Thank you man